# Use array as keys and generate values to produce a hash

Tags: ruby

I have an array. As example:

```
a = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
```

I want to convert it to a hash:

```
h = { "foo" => randomvalue1, "bar" => randomvalue2, "baz" => randomvalue3 }
```

I come up with following way:

```
Hash[* a.map { |value| [value, randomvalue_generator] }.flatten]
```

My experience with Ruby quite limited, but have a feeling that there should be simler way of doing this. Mainly, I am interested in reducing code complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your way is fine except you do not need to `flatten` or `splat`

```
a = ["foo", "bar","baz"]
Hash[a.map{ |k| [k, rand(5)] }]
# {"foo"=>1, "bar"=>0, "baz"=>2}
```

There many other ways to accomplish this but I like your original solution.

```
a.each_with_object({}){ |k, h| h[k] = rand(5) }

a.inject({}){ |h, k| h[k] = rand(5); h }

a.inject({}){ |h, k| h.merge k => rand(5) }

Hash[a.zip a.map{ |_| rand(5) }]
```

Comment: `Hash[a.zip([*0..50].sample(3))]`

Comment: @YevgeniyAnfilofyev nice one!